# Extension loading frontend layout on admin

Tags: adminhtml, extensions, layout

I *believe* this is the case, at least. The problem is with an extension called [VehicleFits](http://www.vehiclefits.com/), ([it's also on GitHub](https://github.com/vehiclefits/Vehiclefits-Magento)).

EDIT: Here's a bit more configuration info. Magento EE 1.13, VAF 1.34.

Originally, the issue was that a `_setActiveMenu()` call was causing an error with the text:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in /path/to/my/magento/site/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 104
```

Looking at the blocks available at the time of the `_setActiveMenu()` call, I see that it's all frontend stuff (cart_sidebar, top.search, etc), and the menu block is not available.

Any clues as to where I should look to see why the frontend layout is being loaded, and how I can ensure that the adminhtml layout is loaded instead?

Thanks!

**Some more information...**

Here's the definition of the menu from the plugin:

```
 <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <vaf translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>Vehicles</title>
            <sort_order>25</sort_order>
            <children>
                <vehicleslist translate="title">
                    <title>Vehicle List</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <local translate="title">
                            <title>Manage</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/definitions</action>
                        </local>
                    </children>
                </vehicleslist>
                <schema translate="title">
                    <title>Schema</title>
                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <local translate="title">
                            <title>Manage</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/schema</action>
                        </local>
                    </children>
                </schema>
            </children>
        </vaf>
    </menu>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <vaf translate="title">
                        <title>Vehicle Fits</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <vehicleslist translate="title">
                                <title>Vehicle List</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                <children>
                                    <local translate="title">
                                        <title>Manage</title>
                                        <action>adminhtml/definitions</action>
                                    </local>
                                </children>
                            </vehicleslist>
                            <schema translate="title">
                                <title>Schema</title>
                                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                                <children>
                                    <local translate="title">
                                        <title>Manage</title>
                                        <action>adminhtml/schema</action>
                                    </local>
                                </children>
                            </schema>
                        </children>
                   </vaf>
               </children>
           </admin>
       </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! Great first question. Extension questions are welcomed - but have you tried filing an issue on the author's Github?

Comment: It crossed my mind, but somehow I feel like it's something that I'm doing wrong, as opposed to the extension.I'll definitely file an issue though.

Comment: Following the advice of @philwinkle, I've opened an issue on the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/vehiclefits/Vehiclefits-Magento/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing the plugin did the trick.